# How to handle dom using electron-vue

Tags: test-design, test-strategy, electron

Problem :

The boilerplate used `electron-vue`.
The following code is part of the `src/renderer/main.js` file.

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron').remote
const win = new BrowserWindow({enableRemoteModule: true, show: true})
win.loadURL('https://localhost:8080/login')
let contents = win.webContents
console.dir(contents)
let input_id = contents.fromId('SiteId')
if (!process.env.IS_WEB) Vue.use(require('vue-electron'))
Vue.http = Vue.prototype.$http = axios
Vue.config.productionTip = false
/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  components: { App },
  router,
  store,
  template: '<App/>'
}).$mount('#app')
```

When I run this code, a window appears, but an error occurs at `contents.fromId('SiteId')`.

I was wondering if there is a way to access the `HTML DOM` loaded in windows or how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

self-answer.

```
contents.on('did-finish-load', ()=>{
   let code = `const input_id = document.getElementById("SiteId")
             input_id.value = '123'`
   contents.executeJavaScript(code)
})
```

Just write the JavaScript you want to run in the handler that is executed when the load is complete and call executeJavaScript() of contents.

You can also handle the dom using JQuery if you wish. Additionally, you can use the xpath using document.evaluate().

```
contents.on('did-finish-load', ()=>{
  // HINT ES 6
  // let code = `const input_id = document.getElementById('SiteId')
  //           input_id.value = '12345'`

  // HINT JQuery
  // let code = `const input_id = $("#SiteId")
  //           input_id.val('12345')`

  // HINT xpath
  let code = `let input_id = document.evaluate("//input[@id='SiteId']", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null)
            console.dir(input_id)
            input_id = input_id.iterateNext()
            input_id.value = '12345'`

  contents.executeJavaScript(code)
})
```